# html to .doc converter in Python?

Tags: python, ms-word, pisa

I am using pisa, which is an HTML to PDF conversion library for Python.

Does there exist the same thing for a Word document: an HTML to .doc conversion library for Python?

Comment: Why would you want this? MS Word can read HTML.

Comment: I have the same problem: I have a html that uses pisa to convert to pdf and I want to do the same thing with word. its a big document, ~20 pages, using the same piece of code to generate the html and then export thru pisa or something else would be great.

Comment: @Eric: Recently, I had the same problem. Just wondering, did you find a solution to convert HTML to Word .docx? Thanks.

Comment: @tao.hong : Did you manage to solve your problem? I am looking for a suitable open source solution too. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You could use win32com from the [pywin32](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) python extensions for windows, to let MS Word convert it for you. A simple example:

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

doc = word.Documents.Add('example.html')
doc.SaveAs('example.doc', FileFormat=0)
doc.Close()

word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 5):

Though I am not aware of a direct module that can allow you to convert this, however:

1. You can convert *HTML* to *plain text* first using the [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) module.
2. After that, you can use this the [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) module to convert the text to a *doc* or a *docx* file.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else lands here attempting to convert the other way around, the above code works, but you need to modify the FileFormat value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839952.aspx

Example: Filtered html is 10, instead of 0.

Answer (score -1):

Update with a python3.x fix this:

```
from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx

new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
new_parser.parse_html_file("html_filename", "docx_filename")
#Files extensions not needed, but tolerated
```

Comment: any thoughts on how you'd use this if you're converting an HTML string rather than having to save an HTML file first?