# How can i convert html to word docx in python?

Tags: python, html, ubuntu-16.04, doc

```
import pypandoc
output = pypandoc.convert_file('file.html', 'docx', outputfile="file1.docx")
assert output == ""
```

It is generating new docx file but ignoring styles.

Can any one tell me how to generate new docx file with styles?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035183/how-can-i-create-a-word-document-using-python and http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html to .doc converter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226095/html-to-doc-converter-in-python)

Answer (score 15):

In Windows the easiest way will be to use MS Word using `pywin32` plugin. [Here is good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4227062/3042057) answer with example code.

Using pypandoc:

```
output = pypandoc.convert(source='/path/to/file.html', format='html', to='docx', outputfile='/path/to/output.docx', extra_args=['-RTS'])
```

Read [this](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) for extra_args.

Comment: it's working, but pypandoc does not support css styles.

Comment: @СергейЧабаненко you can use `extra_args='--css=custom_file.css'` to include the css file. You can use static file or generate temporary file with python using a template.

Comment: @EminMastizada It seems that the `--css` argument is used when converting *to* HTML but ignored when converting *from* HTML. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [htmldocx](https://pypi.org/project/htmldocx/) in python 3.x:

```
from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx

new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
new_parser.parse_html_file("html_filename", "docx_filename")
#Files extensions not needed, but tolerated
```

Answer (score 1):

please use this library to generate html2docx.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from io import BytesIO
from html2docx import html2docx

def generate_docx(request):
    context = {
    'data': 'Hello, this is your data!',
   }
   html_content_bytes = render(request, 'your_template.html', 
   context).content
   html_content_str = html_content_bytes.decode('utf-8') 
  
   output = BytesIO()
   byte_data = html2docx(html_content_str, output)


   response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.docx'
   response.write(byte_data.getvalue())

   return response
```