# How to generate word document from html in Django?

Tags: python, django, ms-word, doc, django-2.1

Now I use `easy_pdf` for create pdf documents from html templates. Are there any library for make doc/docx files in the same way?

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer [html to .doc converter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226095/html-to-doc-converter-in-python/4227062#4227062). In that answer, author mentioned [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32). From the description:-

> Python extensions for Microsoft Windows Provides access to much of the Win32 API, the ability to create and use COM objects, and the Pythonwin environment.

There are another libraries that you can try: [templated-docs](https://github.com/alexmorozov/templated-docs) and [python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx).

Comment: Unfortunately I can`t use WinApi because the site works on Linux machine (in docker container).

Comment: But `templated-docs` with using DOC template for generate both DOC and PDF seems to suits me too.